# ReactiveUI TwoWay binding a checkbox

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui

I have a simple view with a checkbox and a viewModel with a `[Reactive]` bool property.

I would like a change to the checkbox on the UI to propagate to the viewModel property, but I would also like to have the UI checkbox state get updated when the viewModel property is updated by external factors.

I assumed that a two way binding would do this

`this.Bind(ViewModel, 
    viewModel => viewModel.DepthLabel, 
    view => view._depthLabel.IsChecked)
       .DisposeWith(disposable);`

...but the UI is not responding when the field property changes from external factors.

What can I do to get the UI to update? If this is not what two-way bind is meant for, when should it be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to get the UI to update?

Make sure that the `DepthLabel` source property is set on the dispatcher thread.

For example, in the following sample code, calling `ObserveOnDispatcher()` is required for the `CheckBox` in the view to update:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public bool DepthLabel { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
           .ObserveOnDispatcher()
           .Subscribe(_ => DepthLabel = true);
    }
}
```

Comment: property was set after the timespan, but the UI did not update

Comment: @SlackGroverglow: Did? Does it now?

Comment: I now see that my problem was that my ViewModel did not inherit `ReactiveObject`. Strange how you can still use `[Reactive]` with no errors or warnings.